# ActiveSync not getting connected

Tags: usb, windows-ce, activesync, beagleboneblack

I'm using AM335x Beagle Bone black with WinCE 7 BSP VS 2008 on a Windows 7 PC. I'm using Mobile Device Centre. When the device boots, I'm getting '**USB device not recognized**' pop-up message. I have checked the following.

1. Required catalog items have been added
2. All the USB drivers are in final image
3. Tested it in windows XP 32-bit PC - error persists
4. All the USB drivers are getting loaded
5. Checked for mobile device-based updates in PC

The catalog items I have added are,

1. Core OS\Windows Embedded Compact\Device Drivers\USB\USB Function\USB
   Function Clients\USBFN Serial Client
2. Core OS\Windows Embedded Compact\Device Drivers\USB\USB Function\USB
   Function Support
3. Core OS\Windows Embedded Compact\Applications - End User\Active
   Sync\File Sync
4. Core OS\Windows Embedded Compact\Applications - End User\Active Sync
5. Core OS\Windows Embedded Compact\Shell and User
   Interface\Shell\Graphical Shell\Standard Shell
6. Third Party\BSP\AM33X_BSP\ARMV7\Drivers\MUSB OTG Driver

Am I missing any catalog item? What else can I verify for ActiveSync connection?

**UPDATE 1:**

This catalog item got included due to dependency. Is it any kind of reason for this issue?

```
Core OS\Windows Embedded Compact\Device Drivers\USB\USB Host\USB
    Host Support
```

As per the logs, I noticed that `serialusbfn.dll` is not getting loaded. How to get it loaded? In the registry its order number is not given.

Comment: Are you sure that the **`USB OTG driver`** (your `Third Party\BSP\AM33X_BSP\ARMV7\Drivers\MUSB OTG Driver`) is working properly (for `USB Client` case)?

Comment: Also, please try by removing `Core OS\Windows Embedded Compact\Applications - End User\Active Sync\File Sync`. It may be silly, but please try once, because in my OSDesign it is disabled, and ActiveSync is working properly

Comment: @Keshava I have removed that catalog item and let it build. I will update once it is done. Meanwhile, could you tell me, how to check whether USB OTG driver is working properly? Thanks.

Comment: May be by using [USB analyser](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=USB+analyser&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&gws_rd=cr&ei=xdTTUrShBcGPrQeEqIC4Cw)?

Comment: @Keshava Actually, I doubt it would be possible using USB analyzer. Because, the device itself is shown as 'Unknown' in Device Manager as it is 'unrecognized'. Am I right?

Comment: Yes. But , here we faced "**USB device not recognized**" issue, just because of some timing issues which got solved by adding some delay etc.. So, AFAIK it's a problem with your USB OTG driver only.. Maybe you need to debug it.. My case, my driver was from scratch, so i was able to debug quickly.

Comment: @Keshava Oh! I will try debugging it. Meanwhile, if you are using Windows 7, Could you tell me what kind of desktop registry settings are required? I referred [this msdn link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee486984(v=winembedded.70).aspx). But, I'm not sure about what all minimal fields required. It has been mentioned that I have to check `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows CE Services\Partners\DeviceID\Services\Synchronization` subkey. But I don't have any entry under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows CE Services\Partners`. Thats why.

Comment: I think if WMDC is installed, no other setup is needed.. Anyway i'll check my registry settings and will inform you

Comment: Even I don't have any entry under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows CE Services\Partners`

Comment: @Keshava Oh! Maybe then it might not be a reason. I removed the catalog item `File Sync`. Still, I don't find any improvement.

Comment: OK. You may need to check USB OTG driver i guess...

Comment: Do you have any idea what else might be reason behind this? other than delay? Thanks.

Comment: hmm.. for this time i don't have any idea. I'll get back if i get some..

Comment: @Keshava Is KITL required for Activesync? If not, could you tell me where is the device ID assigned?

Comment: `KITL` is not required `ActiveSync`. Regarding `DeviceID` , I'll check it and inform you soon.

Comment: @Keshava Is Active Sync working for you in Debug mode?

Comment: Yes, It's working for me in Debug mode too... Haven't you ever tested in release mode?!

Comment: Yes. From the initial stage, I have tried it in Debug mode. I didn't know that would have effect over this. In release mode, its working fine. I'm wondering why it's not working in Debug mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's now working in both Windows 7 and Windows XP.

Previously I was building the BSP in Debug mode. I changed it to Release Mode.

I ensured that KITL is disabled in OS Design and disabled KITL in eboot also when the device boots.

In Windows XP, it gets connected just like that.

In Windows 7, Windows update detected the device and installed drivers for it. It didn't get connected the first time (or maybe I didn't wait for few more minutes). The second time also Windows update installed drivers and got connected. From then, its getting connected every time in 2 minutes. No installation of drivers after that.

I think, due to some timing issues, Active Sync is not getting connected in Debug mode.

As per the ARM A8 User Guide, the reason why KITL and Active Sync can't be together at the same time is,

> The USB RNDIS KITL transport uses a dedicated set of routines to
>   communicate with the kernel. It does not use the standard USB function
>   or OTG stacks. It is critical that all USB drivers be disabled when
>   USB RNDIS KITL is in use. The USB RNDIS KITL implementation
>   automatically disables the standard USB drivers when KITL is active.

Thanks to Keshava and Valter for the continuous help!

Comment: Nice, It worked in release mode! I didn't know that you haven't ever tried release mode, because normally here we will use debug mode only if it's not working with release mode.

And yes, AFAIK, It must be **`timing issue`**...

Or see [THIS ANSWER](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20371754/wince-debug-version-works-release-version-crashes-while-reading-from-stream-de/20381753#20381753). It says another main difference. It may help you.

All the best!

Answer (score 0):

If Windows is not asking for a driver it means that, after the physical connection, the device has provided no valid IDs and this should mean that the low-level USB link is not working as expected.
IIRC the controller is an OTG controller and you need to configure it to behave as both host and device (or device only in your case) when you build the OSImage.

Comment: Could you tell me how to make it behave as both OTG and device in OSDesign?

Comment: Also, Is KITL required for Activesync? If not, could you tell me where is the device ID assigned?

Comment: KITL may use the USB client and if it's enabled you can't use ActiveSync. You can disable KITL from the build options tab of os design properties.

Comment: You should have multiple elements in the catalog and you can choose if you want OTG host and client, client only or host only.

Comment: I disabled KITL in both OS Design and device and tried, but still USB device is not getting recognized. I have provided the list of catalog items I have included in the OS Design. I hope I chose the right ones.

Comment: I have updated the question too. Please check it out.

Comment: You have no host/client/host+client options in the OTG driver? No USB function driver somewhere in the BSP?

Comment: No, No such options in OS Design. It worked when KITL was disabled in Release mode. I'm currently trying it in Debug mode.